# PHP Sessions not playing ball

Tags: php, mysql, session

So i'm basically messing around with my own cms type system at the moment and running into some problems with php sessions. Below is a rough explanation on what i have,

All the SQL is working fine as if i remove the sessions i get no login errors (unless i put in incorrect credentials),

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE username='$user' AND password='$pass_md'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Error: " . mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

if($rows == 1){
 $_SESSION['expire'] = time() + (10 * 60); 
 $_SESSION['id'] = $data['id'];
 header("Location: admin.php");
} 
else {
header("Location: ulogin.php?login=failed");
}
```

So in admin.php i have this,

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!(isset($_SESSION['id']))){
 header("Location: ulogin.php");
}
?>
```

My issue is it is logging me in and then passing me straight back to ulogin.php so i'm assuming i have an empty session however i am inserting the user id into the session.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, i'm probably missing something pretty obvious, i'm not the most advanced php developer so yeh, need some more eyes on it.

Thanks

Comment: do you do `session_start()` in the index.php?

Comment: You need `session_start()` in all scripts which access the `$_SESSION`

Comment: At the beginning of your file, do you have a `session_start()` in your first block?

Comment: Also, your code doesn't look very robust with the `die()` and `isset()`s.

Comment: have you started the session in the first script? Tried putting session_write_close() before the redirect?

Comment: Did you session_start() ulogin.php too?

Comment: Yes i have session_start() on my login page...

Comment: This question has been asked a thousend times, this mistake is very common, the php manual could be much clearer about it, though!

Comment: Do you have and `id` field in your database, and what does it contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, because i was using 2 seperate login pages (One for the frontend and one for the backend) i was missing;

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
```

from one of my login pages, sorted now, thanks all for the comments that actually made me triple check that!

Comment: If youre building something new you really shouldnt use `ext/mysql` (the `mysql_*` functions). Instead you should use [`Mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: additionally you should be using exit; after your header redirections; as at times these can cause issues if not placed.